# ruler shows way higher value than n>mesh display>edge info>Length. how to fix?

Tags: export, edit-mode

i made an model which i wanted to 3d print. for editing i used n>mesh display>edge info>Length. when i exported it into an stl and tryed to import my model into another program it showd that my obj was like 10m long instead of 10cm. i went back to blender and checked my distances with the ruler tool. heres what i got:[image: ruler and edge length]

so im asking now: what do i have to do to fix that? ill take everything but an solution that makes both measurements the same would be best. cause id like to use blender for ""cad"" applications.

-laurin

Comment: Your object is probably scaled. In object mode use "Ctrl+A" to apply scale so that it has a scale set to one and keep its inner geometry.